# Primefaces, periodical update when idle

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, auto-update, ajax-polling

I want to auto update datatable (on client) when user is idle. I'm using Primefaces 3.5 with glassfish and my idea was following:

I've `boolean autoUpdate` variable in bean. And user can turn on/off the auto update.

I created two components: `p:poll` and `p:idleMonitor`.

The `idleMonitor` has two events, which trigger the update

```
<p:ajax event="idle" oncomplete="myPoll.start();" />
<p:ajax event="active" oncomplete="myPoll.stop();" />
```

This part is ok. The problem is, how to disable `idleMonitor` when `autoUpdate` is set to `False`? When I do

```
<h:panelGroup id="updatePanel" rendered="#{cc.attrs.bean.autoUpdate}">
....
</h:panelGroup>
```

it works only if I start with `autoUpdate = false` and I can switch the mode only once. Once it's rendered it can't be changed. I've also tried

```
<p:ajax event="idle" oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.bean.autoUpdate ? 'myPoll.start();' : ''}" />
```

but it didn't work neither. The `#{cc.attrs.bean.autoUpdate}` is never changed. Even I'm calling upadte on it and I can see the variable changed on another place.

So, my question is: Is there any way how to disable idleMonitor, after it was rendered? Or what is the better solution for optional periodical update for idle's user?

Comment: So you want Idle monitor but for only once? You don't want that option when second time user goes idle?

Comment: No, I want Idle monitor each time when user goes idle. But only if he has the `autoUpdate` sets to `True`. It means, he can switch between `True` and `False` during a session without reloading a page.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried p:outputPanel instead of h:panelGroup? First one harmonies better is my subjective perception.

Answer (score 0):

Your autoUpdate variable is evaluated only at **render time**. (at page load)

```
#{cc.attrs.bean.autoUpdate}
```

That's why js doesn't know about its modifications.

**Solution 1**, rerender a js code:

```
<p:ajax event="idle" update="afterIdle" />
<h:panelGroup id="afterIdle">
 <h:outputScript>
  if ('#{cc.attrs.bean.autoUpdate}' == 'true') 
   myPoll.start();
 </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**Solution 2**: keep a js variable updated on autoUpdate (somehow, for example with remoteCommand):

```
<p:ajax event="idle" oncomplete="myFunction()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction(){
  if (jsAutoUpdate) myPoll.start();
 }
</script>
```

**Solution 3**: primefaces idleMonitor widget has a stop() function, which stops idle monitoring.